# d3.time.scale() not working date inputs on IE 10 and Firefox

Tags: firefox, d3.js, internet-explorer-10

I am trying to build a bubble chart using d3.js. I want my bubble color to be filled according to date. I used the following function to generate color based on the date given:

```
color = d3.time.scale().domain([new Date('2013-07-23'), new Date('2013-06-01')]).range(['#98E698', '#1E7B1E']);
```

And while creating the graph I am calling it

```
.style("fill", function(d) {return colour(new Date("2013-07-8")); });
```

The above code is working fine only for Chrome. In IE 10 and Firefox the `color` function is returning NaN instead of a colour code. Why?

Comment: Try using like d3.select(this).style("fill", currentColor);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
return color(new Date("2013-07-08"))
```

with `color` spelled correctly and a 0 in front of the 8 works in IE10. Reading the `new Date(string)` [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), it looks like a [two digit month](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) is expected. In chrome:

```
>new Date("2013-07-8") 
Mon Jul 08 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
```

in IE10:

```
>new Date("2013-07-8") 
Invalid Date 
>new Date("2013-07-08") 
Sun Jul 7 17:00:00 PDT 2013
```

To fix this problem - clean up your dates by adding a zero when necessary or use [d3.time.format] to change strings into dates[3](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting):

```
>var format = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d"); 
>format.parse("2013-07-8") 
Mon Jul 8 00:00:00 PDT 2013
```

(this works in IE10)